# Check if input string exists in file

Tags: command-line, files, grep, sh

You must **read string1**, what should I do? Here's my code:

```bsh
#!/bin/sh
echo "Enter your sting: "
read read string1
if [ grep -q $string1 file.txt ];then
   echo "Found it"
else
   echo "Sorry this string not in file"
fi
exit 0
```

Comment: I gather you want to read a string and check if the string is contained in `file.txt`?

Comment: Yes that what I want

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Your `read` command is wrong, it should be `read string1` (and you should use `-r` to prevent `read` from mangling backslashes: `read -r string1`);
- The test is also wrong, it should be `if grep -q $string1 file.txt` since you're not evaluating the output of `grep` but rather its return value;
- You should pass the `-F` option to `grep` to prevent it from interpreting regular expression metacharacters as such: `if grep -qF $string1 file.txt`
- You should double-quote `$string1` to prevent a potential filename expansion and / or word splitting: `if grep -qF "$string" file.txt`

Other notes:

- The `exit 0` at the end is redundant and not really needed, as if the script manages to reach that point without errors it returns `0` anyway;
- [ShellCheck](http://www.shellcheck.net/) is a very useful resource to debug scripts.

So the script corrected according to the above would be:

```bsh
#!/bin/sh
echo "Enter your sting: "
read string1
if grep -qF "$string1" file.txt;then
   echo "Found it"
else
   echo "Sorry this string not in file"
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it's always better to store the result, number of matches in this case, in a variable.

That said, you have 2 choices, use `grep -c` to count matched lines

```
count=$(grep -c "$string1" file.txt)
```

Or pipe the matched lines to `wc` from `grep -o` (--only-matches)

```
count=$(grep -o "$string1" file.txt | wc -l)
```

This will be the complete script with the second option

```
#!/bin/sh
echo "Enter your string: "
read string1
count=$(grep -o "$string1" file.txt | wc -l)
if [ $count != 0 ];then
   echo "Found it ($count times)"
else
   echo "Sorry this string not in file"
fi
exit 0
```

Also, you wrote `read` twice.